# Failed to open stream even though place exists

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a file using:

```
require_once '../config/configVARS.php';
```

but I get the error:

```
Warning: require_once(../config/configVARS.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..../classes/FileHandler.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config/configVARS.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in ..../classes/FileHandler.php on line 2
```

If I try to include a file on the same folder i don't have any error (for ex. when I copy the configVARS file to the same folder i'm able to include it).

I checked permissions and that's not it (neither ownership).

Any ideas? what can cause it?

Comment: Check that the file actually is there, if you are unsure that you are using the right file-name, use an absolute path instead of a relative one. The magic constant `__DIR__` contains the absolute location of the file you write it into, so `require_once __DIR__  . '/concrete/path/to/file.php';` is often more distinct as you actually seem to know *where* exactly the file exists, so a pre-configured include directory where to look in does not seem necessary.

Comment: great answer. if you'll post it as an answer you'll get my vote for sure!

Comment: I was having a hard time till I realized that linux is case sensitive, I was retrieving a file ending with upper case file.PHP but the real file was just lower case, be careful in this matter too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the file actually is there, if you are unsure that you are using the right file-name, use an absolute path instead of a relative one.

The [magic constant `__DIR__`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) contains the absolute location of the file you write it into, so

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/concrete/path/to/file.php';
```

is often more distinct as you actually seem to know where exactly the file exists - a pre-configured include directory where to look in does not seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Relative includes are always a tricky subject, the relative path may be different to what you think dependent upon the file that you are including it in. Best practice is to use an absolute reference, commonly through prefixing with a defined constant, e.g:

```
define('BASE_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

require_once(BASE_PATH . 'path_to_include');
```

It is better explained here:

http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/

Comment: There already is a constant, you do not even need to define, it's called `__DIR__` and it is independent to the document root of the webserver which might not be the root path of an application (unless you only want to host a single application on the whole server).

Comment: I know of this constant, the majority of the time there is only a single application running on the server.

Comment: Well if the site grows, this is likely not to be the case any longer and then the integration hassle starts only because not giving a more flexible solution in the first place. Also what's in `$_SERVER` depends what the environment gives you. That is a dependency not under your full control and won't work for example in CLI. Not that those are the issues you run over in the first place, but why make things complicated in the first place? Apart from that, just for the concrete code OP posted, the define you suggest is normally just not necessary. Keep it simple. ;)

Comment: Point taken. It's always best practice to have a global include with a constant defined as the base path, either through as you suggested __DIR__ or getcwd(). The majority of large applications follow this approach.

Comment: Oh now you actually need a global require line that needs your suggested base constant to define that base constant ;). Anyway, a suggestion I can give is to actually speak with developers of these large applications if they still think that the approach is good. See the history of such project and also look into more modern software, that is more work, however has more value and gives more insight to understand why something was solved in a specific way, not only how.